Apps Script won't step into the If part of an If Else statement when the if condition is true
The code was actually fine. The debugger was broken and crashing early and there was a crash much much later in the code that wasn't error producing. There was no information here that could be learned from and it was a waste of everyone's time. sorry

Your code is not reproducible. Please provide a [mcve] that  reproduces the problem.  Your code has unefined variables making it impossible for us to reproduce the problem easily.

The code doesn't look to be complete. Is it a function? This is about reading sheet values, please describe the sheet and add sample values (input and the expected result).

The problem isn't reproducible. I have almost identical code blocks running fine.. I'll add a minimal one for concept I guess

There was an error causing the debug log to abruptly stop when the if condition became true, misleading me into believing it was crashing at that point. It was actually running that part fine and crashing on a part that was incorrect due to poor version control. I had to come up with a different way to debug to find it. I'm going to delete this question, since there is no actual problem in it. Sorry for wasting your time
